# Are Fmaj7 and C major chord the same in Guitar?

Tags: guitar

Are Fmaj7 and C major chord the same in Guitar ?

I have some confusion in these two  chord

Comment: What is your confusion caused by?

Comment: @Tim confusion has cleared  actually  i was thinking  that  they have same note

Comment: Not even close.  C = (C, E, G) and Fmaj7 = (F, A, C, E).  There are 2 notes in common.  But they are not the same.

Comment: I suppose one could argue that C-E-G is an Fmaj9 with the root omitted, but that seems like a stretch (metaphorically speaking.)

Comment: Is this one https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/114268/ well researched?

Comment: @jasmine I hope the accepted answer solves your problem, but it would help if you were more explicit about what you're asking about. E.g. did you have a misconception about what notes (note names) constitute each chord, or about specific guitar chord diagrams, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They certainly aren't the same *sounding*. But if you mean fingering, then by leaving the top string open, and second string on the 1st fret, by moving the fingers on the 5th and 4th strings across one string (towards the floor), the *shape* is virtually the same. 4 or 5 strings played will suffice for each.

However, if you mean the same *notes*, then no, they're different. C = CEG, F maj7 = FACE. Only two matching notes.

Answer (score 3):

Fmaj7 = FACE
C = CEG

They share 2 notes.  Just move F up to G, A down to G, and you have C.

Answer (score 3):

`C` major doesn't have the tone `F`. `F` is the root of an `F` chord. Categorically you can say they aren't the same chord.

But...

There is a similarity in fingering vis a vis the open `C` major chord.

```
    C : x 3 2 0 1 0

Fmaj7 : x 3 3 2 1 0

          *     * *
```

The way those chord diagrams work is: numbers are for frets, arranged left to right for 6th to 1st string, `x` means "don't play that string."

The `C` chord is standard open position.

The `Fmaj7` is an *inverted chord* where the bass is `C`, you could also play the chord as `xx3210` so the bass tone on the 4th string would be the root `F`.

I put asterisks under the 5th, 2nd, and 1st strings to show those tones *are the same between the two chords.* Only two tones change between the chords. That shows a certainly similarity between the two chords, but they are not exactly the same.

In terms of strings and pitch letters, on the 4th and 3rd strings, from the `C` to `Fmaj7` chord, tones `E` ascends to `F` and `G` ascends to `A`.

Comment: You could also play Fmaj7 with the 6th string 1st fret. That brings it back to root position. And for that matter, the C often has 6th string 3rd fret. All the time when I play it...

Comment: @Tim, yes, but I was trying to think of voicing/fingering that made the chord appear most similar, figuring that could be part of the confusion. You could choose other voicings to highlight a dissimilarity, but that didn't seem to be the point of the question.