# Arpeggiated chords: which order to play, and does it matter if it's right or left hand?

Tags: piano, chords, arpeggios

In an answer [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/114268/how-do-you-know-which-order-to-play-stacked-notes-in) Carl Witthoft says the default is that arpeggiated chords are played from lowest to highest. Does this convention apply to both hands? E.g. in Measure 8 of the 2nd movement of this Beethoven sonatina, the arpeggiated chord is on the left hand, in which order should it be played?

[image: Arpeggiated LH chord in Beethoven Sonatina in F Major, mvmt 2, m. 8]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chords, by default, are arpeggiated from the lowest pitch to the highest, unless otherwise indicated, regardless which hand is playing them. This is the case with the Beethoven example in the question.

There is a symbol for downward-arpeggiated chords. It looks like the same "squiggly line", but has an arrow at the bottom, pointing downwards.

[image: Down arpeggio symbol]
(Image source: [Steinberg help](https://steinberg.help/dorico/v2/en/dorico/topics/notation_reference/notation_reference_arpeggio_signs_c.html))

Comment: Regardless left or right hand? (p.s. That chord with 6 notes has to be played by two hands?)

Comment: @GrandAdagio It's just illustrating the symbol. And yes, handedness doesn't matter, even if the arpeggio spans both hands.

Comment: Worth noting (!) that in a piece with arps that go up in some places, down in others, both may have arrowheads, to save confusion. Particularly in guitar music, where arps abound.

Comment: @Tim I'm hunting around for an example score, but I don't know the literature. Any suggestions?

Comment: Arpeggiated chord is the same as rolled chord? Same notation?

Comment: @GrandAdagio arpeggiation is a more general term that includes rolling. Rolled chords are typically denoted by a vertical, squiggly line.

Comment: @Aaron So I should have better titled this question "Rolled chords..."?

Comment: @GrandAdagio I think that's your call. But if you change it, I would still keep the word "arpeggiated" somewhere in the post in case that's the search term someone chooses.